# How to define a templated subclass of a template?

Tags: c++

I just updated to GCC 4.8.2 (from 4.7), and am now getting a warning for the following code:

```
template <class T_base>
class factory {
private:
    template <class T>
    struct allocator : factory {
                    // ^ warning: invalid use of incomplete type 'class factory<T_base>'
    };
};
```

To avoid the warning, I tried to define `struct allocator` outside of `factory`, but now get the following error:

```
template <class T_base>
class factory {
private:
    template <class T>
    struct allocator;
};

template <class T_base, class T>
struct factory<T_base>::allocator<T> : factory<T_base> {
                     // ^ error: too few template-parameter-lists
};
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a syntax for the above construct that avoids both the warning and the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to spell it like this:

```
template <class T_base>
template <class T>
struct factory<T_base>::allocator : factory<T_base>
{
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Makes sense now that I know what is needed :) Thanks!

Comment: It's a bit annoying that `factory` isn't a _nested-type-name_ (or whatever) in this context >.<

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for declaring a nested template is to have two separate template argument lists:

```
template <class T_base>
template <class T>
struct factory<T_base>::allocator : factory<T_base> {
};
```

However, I’m questioning which semantic sense this piece of code makes.

Comment: @KerrekSB Never mind, it was a copy & paste error. I’ve corrected it.